# number of integer solutions for $2^x\cdot 3^y$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-factorization

Can someone help me figure out how to calculate the number of integer solutions to the equation: $N\ge2^x3^y|x,y\in\Bbb Z+$

For example if $N$ is $30$ we have $2\cdot 3$, $2^2\cdot 3$, $2^3\cdot 3$, $2\cdot 3^2$ so $4$ solutions

I know the number of integer solutions to $N\ge2^x$ is just $\left \lfloor \ln{N}/\ln{2} \right \rfloor $
So I was thinking something along the lines of taking the sum of $\log_2\left(\frac{N}{3^i}\right)$ from $i=1..(\log_3(N))$

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: For clarification, you mean to say $x,y\in \{1,2,3,\dots\}$?  or do you mean $x,y\in\{0,1,2,3,\dots\}$?  It should be pointed out that $1\geq 2^x3^y$ for all $x,y\in\{0,-1,-2,-3,\dots\}$, so as it is written the answer is infinity for every $N$.

Comment: For $N=30$, I count $1,2,4,8,16,3,6,12,24,9,18,27$ as solutions !?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen if he is ignoring zero, that would invalidate $1,2,4,8,16,3,9,27$ as they have one or fewer prime factors.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to put the + I meant only the positive integers. So yes (1,2,3...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

The problem $2^x 3^y \le 30$ can be solved graphically as follows.

Taking the logarithm of both sides and simplifying, we get

\begin{align}
   2^x 3^y &\le 30 \\
   (\ln 2)x + (\ln 3)y &\le \ln 30 \\
\end{align}

The line above is the line described by $(\ln 2)x + (\ln 3)y = \ln 30$.
The indicated lattice points are the $(x,y)$ solutions to $ 2^x 3^y \le 30$

Answer (score 2):

You want to count all the points with positive integer coordinates which lie on or below the line

$$ y=-x\log_3(2)+N\log_3(N)\tag{1}$$

which one obtains by taking $\log_3$ of both sides of

$$ 2^x3^y=N $$

and solving for $y$.

A formula for computing the number $C(N)$ of points having positive integer coordinates and lying on or below the line given by $(1)$ is

$$ C(N)=\sum_{k=1}^{\left\lfloor\log_2(N/3)\right\rfloor}\left\lfloor\log_3\left(\frac{N}{2^k}\right)\right\rfloor\tag{2} $$

For example, for $N=243$ this gives

$$ C(243)=\sum_{k=1}^{6}\left\lfloor\log_3\left(\frac{243}{2^k}\right)\right\rfloor=4+3+3+2+1+1=14 $$
Here is a [GeoGebra link](https://ggbm.at/CNJWcxp2) with a slider where you can change the value of $N$.

Below is a static illustration.

[image: straignt line and integer points]

Comment: Looks line @stevengregory and I were thinking along the same line and both using GeoGebra.

Comment: The advantage is that your line passes through the "nice" point (0,5)

Comment: I have added the formula for computing the number of qualifying points.